# Oracle - Transferring records between two instances, via synonyms?

Tags: sql, oracle

We need to migrate data between several Oracle database instances.

We want to dump the records from one table in one instance, and import it into an identical table on another instance.

The complication is that the Oracle username we're using doesn't have access to the tables themselves directly - the tables are owned by a separate user. We can't see any of the tables, we only have rights to view synonyms for the tables.

The two tools I've looked at, Oracle SQL Developer and Toad for Oracle will let you dump data from tables (which we could do is we had access to the owner account), and also create a script to re-create the synonyms themselves (as in `DROP SYNONYMY XYZ; CREATE SYNONYM XYZ FOR ABC;`); however, they don't seem to let you specify a synonym and follow that link to dump all the data from that.

Is there any way to tweak either of the above, or a workaround where we might be able to use a tool to dump the data via synonyms?

Failing that, the next best thing will be to write some SQL and script the dump/re-import. Any advice here, caveats, best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues found the Oracle SQLPlus COPY command, which seems to do the job:

```
COPY FROM username/password@hostname:port/SERVICENAME TO username_owner/password@hostname:port/SERVICENAME APPEND TABLE1 USING SELECT * from TABLE1;
```

It will copy all the values, and in this case append (although you can also create the table, or insert into the table) the values into a table on a separate Oracle DB instance.

The only caveat is that the SQLPlus manual says it's going to be obsoleted (not sure why), however, I just checked 11G, and the command is definitely still there.

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 1):

Is [DB Link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm) useful in your situation?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have permissions to create the link =(.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to talk to your DBA's about this and get the correct access to the data owner or have the DBA's create you a database link as suggested by Chin Boon.

A rough and (very) crude method to get the data from one instance into another with no access other than select on the source would be to spool the output from the source into a delimited file and then import that data into the target database (using either external tables or if your access doesn't allow you to create external tables then some other custom built app in java or the like).

My reservations with the above solution (if you can call it that) is that if your data volume is very large the delimited file would become unwieldy very quickly. So my initial point is probably your best option, ask your DBA's to do this for you as their access will enable them to perform the operation very efficiently.